# Backstack навигация фрагментов

Tags: android, android-fragment

Всем привет.

У меня есть 3 фрагмента. Пусть **А, B, C**.

И стоит следующая задача: При открытии активити я открываю фрагмент **А**.

Из фрагмента **А**, я могу перейти на фрагменты **B** или **С**. Ну и по нажатию на бек выхожу с приложения.

из фрагмента **B** я могу вернуться (back press) назад к **А** или перейти дальше на **С**.

Из **С** я могу только вернуться на **А**. (back press)

Теперь к реализации.

Открываю активити с фрагментов **А**, *НЕ добавляю* транзакцию в бекстек.

Далее допустим открываю **В**, транзакцию *добавляю* в бекстек, чтобы я мог вернуться назад к **А**.

Далее перехожу в **С**. Тут мне надо как-то убрать из бекстека **В** и добавить **С**.
Вот собственно не могу найти как мне реализовать переход от **В** к **С**

Comment: Просто не добавляйте С в бекстек

Comment: Думал об этом, но тогда если я с А, перейду на С. то не смогу вернуться на А. разве что при переходе с А на другой фрагмент ставить проверку добавлять С в стек или нет

Answer (score 1):

Из фрагмента **B** открывайте фрагмент **C** с помощью метода `replace` вместо `add`, тогда фрагмент **B** автоматически удалится(замениться) фрагментом **C** в backstack.

Из фрагмента **A** оставьте открытие **C** с помощью `add`.

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же ситуация, решил топорным способом:
1)Создал переменную lastFragment, которой присваивалось значение последнего фрагмента. Изначально присвоил ей значение FragmentA;
2)Переопределил onBackPressed в активити. И если lastFragment != FragmentA то , то принудительно открывался FragmentA, в ином случае - выход из приложения.

Примерный код:

```
public class SuperActivity extends Activity {

    private Fragment lastFragment = new FragmentA(); 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        changeFragment(new FragmentA()); //загружаем первый фрагмент
        //...
        //changeFragment(new FragmentB());
        //changeFragment(new FragmentC());
        //и т.д.
    }

    public void changeFragment(Fragment fragment){ //можно вызывать из фрагментов  - ((SuperActivity)getActivity()).changeFragment(fragmentB)
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

        lastFragment = fragment;  //устанавливаем значение последнего фрагмента
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (lastFragment instanceof DialogFragment) {
            //выход
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            changeFragment(new FragmentA());
        }
    }
}
```